# Incremental search in android using Volley library?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley, incremental-search

I have somehow implemented incremental search in android using AsyncTask. In incremental search an API is called for each character entered in edit text to get suggestions from server. For example,

```
User types a -> API is called.
User types ab -> API is called.
User types abc -> API is called.
```

This makes three API calls for a, ab and abc respectively. If a user is still typing then all the previous requests (e.g. requests of a and ab) will be cancelled and the last request (abc) will be served only to avoid delays.

Now I want to implement this using Volley library for better performance. Could anybody help me how can I achieve this functionality using volley specially the mechanism of cancelling all the previous request and serve the last request only to get suggestions from server.

**NOTE:** I couldn't find regarding this that's why posting it here. Please do guide me because I am new to android and really in need of answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to implement a `TextWatcher` to listen to change in edit text. 
Depending on the requirement of the changed text, you cancel and add a request to queue.

```
private RequestQueue queue = VolleyUtils.getRequestQueue();


private static final String VOLLEY_TAG = "VT";
private EditText editText;
...

 TextWatcher textChangedListener = new TextWatcher() {

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.length() != 0) {
                // first cancel the current request with that tag
                queue.cancelAll(VOLLEY_TAG);
                // and then add a new one to queue
                StringRequest stringRequest = 
                     new StringRequest("http://blabla/servlet?param=" + s, 
                     new Listener<String>() {
                       // request callbacks
                     };
                stringRequest.setTag(VOLLEY_TAG);
                queue.add(stringRequest);
            } 
        }
  };

editText.addTextChangedListener(textChangedListener);
```

Just remember that this design will gobble up bandwidth. A better way is to use `Handler.post()` to wait for several seconds before firing a request.